# Where is the documentation for dictionary generators in Python 3?

Tags: python, dictionary

I mean this:

```
>>> d = {a : a ** 2 for a in range(7)}
>>> d
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36}
```

I managed to find these resources:

- http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dict%20comprehension
- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

These seem to be just tutorials; I want to find it in the documentation itself.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: That's for Python 2 (although admittedly, that part hasn't changed much in Python 3).

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the ["Displays for lists, sets and dictionaries" section](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) of the expressions chapter of the reference documentation.

That section deals with both defining literal lists, sets and dictionaries, as well as comprehension expressions for those types.

> For constructing a list, a set or a dictionary Python provides special syntax called “displays”, each of them in two flavors:
>
> - either the container contents are listed explicitly, or
> - they are computed via a set of looping and filtering instructions, called a comprehension.